# How to see a large image in a smaller window without reshaping image in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I want to place a large image in a smaller window so that at one time only a small fixed portion of image is displayed and when it is drag down or up or left or right, below image gets displayed as it is done in google maps. But when an image is placed in any HTML element, it is either shown full or cropped. Does anyone know How it can be done using HTML, CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: you mean you want scrollbars?

Comment: No scrollbars ! A large image to be seen in smaller window .

Comment: Set the scrollbars to be hidden and then you'll have to write some script to translate mouse drags into scroll events.

Comment: It is similar as displayed in any panoramic image viewer :http://www.onextrapixel.com/examples/panorama-viewer/

Comment: I have got some help from http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/32Y5A/

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `overflow-x:auto` or `overflow-x:visible` as well as `overflow-y:auto` or `overflow-x:visible`.

Comment: Please share online link so i can check ..

Comment: here is the code i tried : https://jsfiddle.net/j0hsacf5/